# Mobile Safari Hover/Link Issue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, mobile-safari

So, here's a weird issue I've come across with Safari on Mobile—I suspect there's one root cause for all of it, but have not been able to figure it out:

- Links wrapping images don't cover the full width and height (as they should screenshot below), just the upper left corner
- Linked Buttons only work on the left half
- Links with: hover will hang on the hover and you have to press through

To make things worse, development tools that are supposed to simulate iPhones don't show anything funky—the whole image/button should be linked, etc.—but when you use the site with an actual device, the above happens.

I know, I know, this feels like such a basic question, but I've been banging my head against it for two days now.

Here's my testing page, but you'll see it intermittently across the site:  https://redcowmn.com/testing-safari-ios-issue/

Is there a stray line of code that tells Safari to misbehave?

Even an ultra simple `<a href="/"><p>Hi</p></a>` acts unreliably.

I'm building on the X Theme framework on Wordpress (where I've got 20+ other sites), Yoast SEO, Wordfence, Gravity Forms, WP Rocket (in Safe Mode), WooCommerce, and Stripe for WooCommerce.

Thanks, folks.

[image: screenshot of link wrapping image, to no avail]

Answer (score 0):

Modal screen!

I had a modal screen acting like some sort ghost element, screwing with the z-index, etc., etc. That's why only parts of the image were active.

Very strange that only Safari had an issue with it, but anyways, that was the issue.

I guess that's what I get for trying to hiding a required ugly embed off screen... :)